# PFQueryTableViewController in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to use this ParseUI Controller called **PFQueryTableViewController** to use **load more** functionality.
Did a bit of google...seemed simple to use but somehow i cannot get it working..
When I ran the following code, there was nothing but a spinner. Just FYI, this view controller is not my main screen. I read an answer about initialising it in AppDelegate but I didn't fully follow it and thought it is not for my case as well.

[image: Table View Cell Identifier]

[image: Table View Cell Custom Class]

[image: Result Screen]

```
import ParseUI
import UIKit

class CouponsPFQueryTableViewController: PFQueryTableViewController {

override init!(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!) {
    super.init(style: style, className: className)

}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    self.parseClassName = "Coupon"
    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
    self.paginationEnabled = true
    self.objectsPerPage = 5
    //self.textKey = "couponItemName"

}

override func viewDidLoad() {

    var nib = UINib(nibName: "CouponsTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "couponsTableViewCell")

}

override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery! {

    var query = PFQuery(className: self.parseClassName)

    if (objects.count == 0)
    {
        query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkOnly
    }

    return query


}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!, object: PFObject!) -> PFTableViewCell!
{

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("couponsTableViewCell") as CouponsTableViewCell!

    cell.testLabel?.text = object["couponItemName"] as NSString
    return cell

}
}
```

Comment: If you override `objectsDidLoad` is it ever called, what objects? Can you run the `query` yourself and get results?

Comment: now i am getting **Could not load NIB in bundle** exception..does it help you figure out what the problem is? i suspect those UINib stuff..which i didn't fully understand..please help!

Comment: Do you have a file called CouponsTableViewCell.XIB?

Comment: You don't need to load and register the table view cell manually, you can just drag a UITableViewCell componente over the table view on the storyboard editor that it will be automatically registered for you. Besides, before you can use Parse you need to call the method Parse.setApplicationId(applicationId: String, clientKey: String). Without this, your app doesn't know where to get data from.